# Accessing shared preferences not working correctly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-contextmenu

I have this piece of code that stores a "toggle" for a specific item on a listview. I use the item's name as the key. However, the result of getBoolean always returns the default value specified in the second parameter. I can't really figure out if I implemented it wrong, or I am overlooking something
For clarification, summonerNames is an arraylist of Strings.

```
        MenuItem toggle = menu.findItem(R.id.postGameNotif);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("summoner_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Log.i(TAG, summonerNames.get(position));
        boolean postNotif = prefs.getBoolean(summonerNames.get(position),false);
        if (postNotif == true) {
            toggle.setTitle("Disable post-game notifications");
            Log.i(TAG,"Disabled");
            editor.putBoolean(summonerNames.get(position), false);
        }
        else {
            toggle.setTitle("Enable post-game notifications");
            Log.i(TAG, "Enabled");
            editor.putBoolean(summonerNames.get(position), true);
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(prefs.getBoolean(summonerNames.get(position),false)));
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to `commit()`

Comment: Add editor.commit() and editor.apply() to reflect changes in your shared prefs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is added values are not committed in shared preference.

After addedin boolean value you missed to commit changes in sharedpreference

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) link

```
 MenuItem toggle = menu.findItem(R.id.postGameNotif);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("summoner_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Log.i(TAG, summonerNames.get(position));
        boolean postNotif = prefs.getBoolean(summonerNames.get(position),false);
        if (postNotif == true) {
            toggle.setTitle("Disable post-game notifications");
            Log.i(TAG,"Disabled");
            editor.putBoolean(summonerNames.get(position), false);
editor.commit()// you need to commit after adding it to sharedpref
        }
        else {
            toggle.setTitle("Enable post-game notifications");
            Log.i(TAG, "Enabled");
            editor.putBoolean(summonerNames.get(position), true);
editor.commit()// you need to commit after adding it to sharedpref
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(prefs.getBoolean(summonerNames.get(position),false)));
        }
```

Comment: Oh geez, how'd I forget that. Thanks

Comment: @BrianLe just a suggestion use this library for sharedpreference https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences https://github.com/Pixplicity/EasyPreferences